# Alternating Row in HTML table Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Alternating Row in HTML table Using jQuery with out tocuhing the existing code.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where is your code?  I understand what you're asking, but are you using tables, divs, other elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will help you

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('#Students > tbody > tr:odd').css("background-color", "green");

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged with jQuery, I guess a jQuery solution would work.

You can use the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) for jQuery, and select all `tr` elements - `$("tr")`.

Then you can use the appropriate method or methods, to do what you want to do with it.

- `.css()` to change some styling
- `.hide()` to hide it,
- `.animate()` to apply some animation to it and so forth.

To name a few...

One example would be:

```
$("tr").css("color", "#ccc"); // Change the font color
```

To get more specific code, you will have to clarify your question and describe what you want to do with the table rows.

Comment: I think you forgot to address the "alternating" part of the question (technically not a question though). Otherwise, excellent answer. :)

Comment: @Zhihao Thanks! Well technically I didn't forget it. I didn't think it was obvious that "Alternating row in HTML table" meant a striped table with odd rows looking different from even rows, so I left that part out and expected the question to be clarified.